# Gridview messed up after scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, adapter

I'm using GridView for my crossword puzzle. And after scrolling the gridview messed up, all the black parts (non leter box) showing letters which not suppose to happen.

Here is my adapter. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
private class CrossWordPuzzleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private int mWidth, mHeight;

    public CrossWordPuzzleAdapter(Context c, int width, int height) {
        mContext = c;
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mWidth * mHeight;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.box_layout, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.numberText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberText);
            holder.charText = (GridViewItem) convertView.findViewById(R.id.charText);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        int x = -1, y = -1;

        if (position < mWidth) {
            x = position;
            y = 0;
        } else {
            x = position % mWidth;
            y = position / mHeight;
        }
        if (mPuzzleBoard.getCharPlace(x, y) != '\0' && mPuzzleBoard.getCharPlace(x, y) != ' ') {
            String questionNoStr = mPuzzleBoard.getQuestionNo(x, y);

            holder.numberText.setText(questionNoStr);
            if (isRevealed) {
                holder.charText.setText("" + Character.toString(mPuzzleBoard.getCharPlace(x, y)).toUpperCase());
                holder.charText.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            holder.charText.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.letter_box_white));
        } else {
            holder.charText.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.letter_box_black));
            convertView.setSelected(false);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: didn't add override annotation ? and return the position value

Comment: it would be hard to track position val. we just never know when this getView is called. it just called randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The error box showing letters are actually previous boxes of Views that contains letters previously. So, after scrolling the position are all messed up, and even though I have set the box colour to black, but I didn't set the box to be empty.

so this is what I do:

```
            else {
                holder.numberText.setText(""); //<< reset the box to empty
                holder.charText.setText(""); //<< reset the box to empty
                holder.charText.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.letter_box_black));
                convertView.setSelected(false);
            }
```